# If $(A/I)^n$ $\cong$ $(A/I)^m$ as modules, why does it follows that $m=n$?

Tags: ring-theory

can anyone explin to me why if $(A/I)^n$ $\cong$ $(A/I)^m$ (isomorphic according to modules) with I being a maximal ideal and (thus $A/I$ is a field) then m=n?

Comment: What is $A$? An arbitrary ring?

Comment: Sorry @JohnM.Campbell. It is a ring with 1, but other than that, yes is is an arbitrary ring.

Comment: i have to show that if i have an Isomorphism between $A^m$ and $A^n$, then it means that n=m. The proof ends by saying that f I is an maximal ideal and $(A/I)^n \cong (A/I)^m$, then n=m because A/I is a field.

Comment: Do you recognize that $\text{some field}^n$ is a vector space and we know a lot about dimensional invariance of vector spaces?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

To expound on the comments:

Presuming $A$ is a commutative ring with $1$ (if not commutative, you have to fuss about $I$ being a two-sided max ideal) then $A/I = k$, a field, and for $n \neq m$, $k^n \not\simeq k^m$ (this is simple in terms of vector spaces to prove), so if $k^n \simeq k^m$, then $n = m$, as required.

To see $k^n\not\simeq k^m$ for $m\neq n$, note an isomorphism of vector spaces takes a basis to a basis. Any basis of $k^n$ has $n$ elements, and similarly for $k^m$, and so if $n\neq m$, there can be no bijection between sets of $n$ elements and $m$ elements. Isomorphisms are bijections. QED.

Comment: Hello @Walkar, can you please explain to me why is A/I=k is a field, then $k^n$ is not isomorphic to $k^m$ is n does not equal m? Thanks.

Comment: Sure, let me edit.

Comment: why does this only work with fields? Why can't I just say that if i have an isomorphism between $A^n$ and $A^m$ with A being a comm ring with 1, then n=m using the same argument u wrote?

Comment: This is the only case you need at this point. Maybe it works in greater generality, but since $I$ is a max ideal, $A/I$ is a field. So this proof works. In other scenarios, you might have to use the property @goblin mentions in his post, but I was just using the case I knew (and you needed).